# Code stop working after I added nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code stop working after I added nested views - AngularJS

Hi guys,

I have a simple page that checks a text input against an set word. In my original code the page works the following ([original code](http://plnkr.co/edit/IPEI1s62SAxO0I3hoffm))

1. If the user does not enter a text the code will prompt them not to leave the text field empty.
2. The text will be compared, if wrong the number of guesses diminishes and then the user will have another chance to enter the right answer.
3. If the user gets the right answer and alert will prompt them of the right answer.
4. If the user runs out tries the page will pop an alert letting the user knows that they run out of guesses and will let them know what the correct word was.

I added nested views to my code and now my code broke, because it is always telling the user that the text field is empty ([nested view code](http://plnkr.co/edit/FO7MurVc7oo1l4mwCTti))

I am not certain if it is an issue with my controllers, but I gone up and down my code and I can't find the issue.

Here is the controller for the game

```
  gameApp.controller('wordController', function($scope)
    {
    $scope.guess = '';
    $scope.guesses = [];
    $scope.guessed= '';
    $scope.allowed = 6;
    $scope.wordToGuess = "Just";
    $scope.guestGuess = "";

    $scope.pushGuess = function () {
        $scope.guesses.push($scope.guestGuess);
        $scope.guessed = $scope.guesses.length;
        $scope.resetGuess();
        $scope.$apply();
    };

    $scope.resetGuess = function() {
        $scope.guestGuess = '';
    };

    $scope.addGuess = function()
        {
        if ($scope.guestGuess === null || $scope.guestGuess === '')
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guessEntry").addClass("has-error"); });
                $("#guessStatus").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down form-control-feedback");
                $("#guessStatus").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback");
                $scope.result = "   Please enter a guess\n\nDon't leave the box empty.";
                alert($scope.result);
            }
        else if ($scope.guestGuess.toLowerCase() == $scope.wordToGuess.toLowerCase())
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guessEntry").removeClass("has-warning").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success has-feedback"); });
                $("#guessStatus").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down form-control-feedback").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback");
                $("#guessStatus").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up form-control-feedback");
                $scope.pushGuess(guestGuess);
                $scope.result = "You have guessed the correct word. Way to go!\n\n\t\t       The word was: ";
                alert($scope.result + $scope.wordToGuess);
                $scope.resetGuess();
            }   
        else if ($scope.guestGuess != $scope.wordToGuess & ($scope.allowed - $scope.guessed) > 1)
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guessEntry").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-warning"); });
                $("#guessStatus").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down form-control-feedback");
                $scope.pushGuess(guestGuess);
                $scope.result = "Please try again!";    
                alert($scope.result);
            }
        else if (($scope.allowed - $scope.guessed) <= 1)
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guessEntry").removeClass("has-warning").addClass("has-error"); });
                $("#guessStatus").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down form-control-feedback");
                $("#guessStatus").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback");
                $scope.guesses.push($scope.guestGuess);
                $scope.guessed = $scope.guesses.length;
                $scope.result = "Game over! The word was: ";    
                alert($scope.result + $scope.wordToGuess);
            }
        $scope.guess = '';
        };
    });
```

Comment: just a tip, try to not using jquery within angularjs, if you want to perfom changes to the DOM, use angularjs directives.

Comment: Are their any raised errors? If not give us some pointers to where your code is failing. Up to which point is it working correctly? Also how does the user submits a guess?

Comment: If I have to point out a omission. `$scope.guestGuess = "";` never gets filled with the user supplied value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's the way that ui-router handles the creation of scopes when it loads views. I don't use it so i don't know what it does (i use and recommend http://angular-route-segment.com/ )

So i put your `wordController` inside of `game.html` and it worked

http://plnkr.co/edit/8ZSyuNAXiC9JX4vBcwtr

I do also kindly recommend you to re-write your app using more `directives` and `factories` than `controllers`, having `factories` control the checking of the guesses, so you'd have an api with a `factory` and use `GuessService.checkInput($scope.guestGuess)` that would make your app more modular and easier to debug and test.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.addGuess = function()
{
    $scope.guestGuess = $("#guessEntry").val();
    if ($scope.guestGuess === null || $scope.guestGuess === '')
        {

        ........ //rest of code
```

I think a reference to the user input was missing.